# How to get value from PreferenceFragment to another Activity

Tags: android, preferences

I need to get value from PreferenceFragment to SplashActivity. How can i do it?

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

public String cityToLoad;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

     ListPreference city = (ListPreference) findPreference("city");
    city.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            cityToLoad = newValue.toString();

            return true;
        }
    });

}}
```

my preferences.xml contains only ListPreference.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have onchange event in list preference. For More http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html

And if you are just using preference tag then you can try below code.

```
city.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {

        Intent newScreen = new Intent(getActivity(), SecondActivity.class);
        newScreen.putExtra("Data", data);
        startActivity(newScreen);

        return true;
    }
});
```